# Trouble with cache woocommerce (PHP)

Tags: wordpress, caching, woocommerce

In woocommerce each variation of my products is updated so often by a API call, the problem is I can't clear product cache, I'm ending up with product pages which the user can't select  variations which had stock 0 (before API calls) but now have stock greater than 0 (after API calls), the UX is as it has the old stock. I tried to do:

```
wc_delete_product_transients( $variation_id );
```

and

```
wc_delete_product_transients( $parent_product_id );
```

The one below solved but stock is now float and I believe it's a issue:

```
 wc_update_product_stock($variation_id, $new_variation_stock);
```